# Map fragment causes Activity to crash after updating targetSDKVersion from 27 to 29

Tags: c#, android, android-fragments, xamarin.android, sdk

I have this map fragment inside that is causing my app to crash:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/map"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```

But changing my target SDK from 29 back to 27 does not break it.
Any ideas why?

Comment: .Check if the SDK versions are same in `build.gradle`  and `AndroidManifest` or not

Comment: @AbhishekDutt Is there a gradle in Xamarin.Android?

Comment: No. But there are some plugins you can use to get thw dependencies from `gradle`.

Answer (score 0):

Just had to add     `<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>` inside the applcation element in the `manifest`.